# Mimicking view when fancy indexing a numpy array: a memory perspective

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 65GB memory mapped numpy array that I want to index:

```
arr = [[...],[...],[...],[...]] #a 65GB memory mapped numpy array
idx = [[...],[...],[...],[...]] #indices for fancy indexing arr
idxed_arr = arr[idx]
```

Learning from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127991/can-i-get-a-view-of-a-numpy-array-at-specified-indexes-a-view-from-fancy-inde) question, there is no easy or memory efficient way to mimic view when fancy indexing a numpy array. Tried many approaches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10019503/2558506), but they were either very slow or I ran out of memory.

My last resort would be to copy few samples at a time(which is very slow). I am open and willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: Why does it need to be a view?  Your first link shows how to write changes back to the map.

Comment: @hpaulj The first link's answer copies the indexed array and makes it a view. My situation is that I am indexing large chunks from a large array. The large indexed array is so big that copying it gives me OOM.

Comment: Give us more information about `idx`?

Comment: Array: Slide windowed MRI image (N\*W\*H\*D\*channel\*slideW\*slideH, (N=220, W=H=240, D=155, channel=4, slideW=slideH=33)), index: Index of ROIs (W\*H\*D\*C). Each index points to a window of a N, and I have about 2,000,000 windows to view for each N.